# Redraw function by using canvas

Tags: html, canvas, graph, qml

I am trying to make a graph in qml by using canvas(the same one which is used in html5).  I need to redraw the screen every second or so.Is there any function which could update the screen? I want to draw the animation graph which can update value every second.

Answer (score 1):

Just use the Timer component :

```
import QtQuick 2.0

Canvas {
    id: myCanvas;
    onPaint: { 
          // do anything you need
    }

    Timer {
         interval: 1000;
         running: true;
         repeat: true;
         onTriggered: { myCanvas.requestPaint ( ); }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please give me an example on onPaint:

Comment: onPaint is the normal code for a Canvas, just like in HTML5, get a context, and use some lineTo/curveTo/moveTo, and some closePath() and fill() or stroke()... Just read the documentation of Qt about Canvas/Context2D and maybe look at the QtQuick examples shared with your copy of Qt5 SDK.